# Query a Relationship Table - SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables with two linked by another. I need to create a query that shows parts that are associated with a specific model number. There are parts that are used across multiple model numbers.

I haven't had to use a table to link two tables previously and I just cannot seem to wrap my head around this.

ModelNumber

1. ModelNumberId
2. ModelNumber
3. Description

Parts

PartId
PartNumber
PartDescription
Price

ModelNumberParts

ModelNumberPartsId
PartId
ModelNumberId

Comment: you need to read about `SQL JOINS`, Internet is a lovely place where you can find all information

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select * from ModelNumber inner join ModelNumberParts
on ModelNumberParts.ModelNumberId = ModleNumber.ModelNumberId
inner join Parts
on ModelNumberParts.PartId = Parts.PartId;
```

You can then reference columns by tablename.columnname.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want parts, you can use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from parts p
where exists (select 1
              from ModelNumberParts mnp
              where mnp.partId = p.partId and
                    mnp.ModelNumberId = @ModelNumberId
             );
```